# Can you not use DataKinds inside Associated Data Types?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families, data-kinds

I have the following type class

```
class BoolHolding h where
  data MyBool b :: 'Bool
```

However, I keep getting the error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Bool’.  Does Haskell not permit this for some reason, or is there away to include the data constructor?  If not, why not?

Comment: `Bool` isn't a data constructor like `True` or `False`, it's a type. You can remove the quote `'`.

Comment: Is this meant to be `data MyBool (b :: Bool)` instead, by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there are 2 issues with what I did.

1: `DataKinds` only requires lifting the constructors, not the data types.  So, the `'Bool` needs only be `Bool`.

2: Kind signatures for `data` must have a return kind of `*`. I can insert data into the kind, but after all the applications have been done, I must eventually have a type.  I did not have this.

For 2, all I had to do was change `data` to `type` and this restriction is no longer present.